# WPF Expander with GridSplitter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

In my WPF window (.NET 4.0) I have Grid with two columns: stretched textbox (or whatever) on the left side and Expander on the right. Also in Expander I have GridSplitter, which is intended to resize both left and right columns when Expander is expanded. But it doesn't work.

This is my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" Name="column"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Aqua"/>

    <Expander Grid.Column="1" Header="Expander" ExpandDirection="Left" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="LightBlue" >
        <Expander.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="Some text Some text Some Text" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Width="5"    
                              ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndCurrent"
                              ResizeDirection="Columns" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Grid>
        </Expander.Content>
    </Expander>
</Grid></Window>
```

---

Appropriate solution is found. 
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" Name="leftColumn"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" Name="rightColumn" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Text="TextBox"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             Background="Aqua" />

    <Expander Grid.Column="2"
              Name="Expander"
              Header="Expander"
              ExpandDirection="Left"
              Background="LightBlue" 
              Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed" 
              Expanded="Expander_Expanded" >
        <TextBlock Text="Some text Some text Some Text" />
    </Expander>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                  Width="5"
                  ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
                  ResizeDirection="Columns"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Height="Auto" 
                  Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Expander, Path=IsExpanded, 
                              Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"/>
</Grid></Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
    private void Expander_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        leftColumn.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        rightColumn.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
    }

    private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rightColumn.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your grid splitter works on the inner grid (in expander) and not on the main grid. Try this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                              Name="column" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Text="TextBox"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 Background="Aqua" />

        <Expander Grid.Column="2"
                  Header="Expander"
                  ExpandDirection="Left"
                  Background="LightBlue">
            <TextBlock Text="Some text Some text Some Text" />
        </Expander>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                      Width="5"
                      ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
                      ResizeDirection="Columns"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Height="Auto" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now you'd need to handle what happens to the last column when the user expands/collapses the expander.

Comment: I was looking for an answer without code-behind or custom converters: AFAIK if Expander is on the left side, it is possible to use only XAML code. But your answer is good enough. I'll post my code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it helps to resolve your problem.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" Name="column"/>

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <Expander Grid.Column="1" Header="Expander" ExpandDirection="Left" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Expander.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="Some text Some text Some Text" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5"    
                          ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndCurrent"
                          ResizeDirection="Columns" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Grid>
        </Expander.Content>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```